# SQL - Retrieving records for in-common Product Codes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, as shown in the image below, I'm trying to query thousands of records of car models with varying Product codes.

I only need to return the records where 2 or more car models have the same Product code as shown in the illustration:

[image: illustration]

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant information, including sample data, table layouts, and desired results.

Comment: It's shown in the illustration I provided

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Please post samples as formatted text inside your questions, don't link to images

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon said, you should better add some more info, not just a picture.

This is a shot in the dark, plain Standard SQL, if your DBMS supports Windowed Aggregate Functions:

```
select product_code, car_model, cnt
from 
 (
   select product_code, car_model, 
      count(*) over (partition by product_code) as cnt
      group by product_code, car_model
   from tab
 ) as dt
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: Thanks this almost does what I need, but is it possible distinct records for Model and ProductId below are what this query returns  1269788 Volkswagen POLO 9  
1269788 Volkswagen POLO 9  
1269788 Volkswagen POLO 9  
1269788 Volkswagen POLO 9   
1269792 Opel VECTRA 18  
1269792 Opel VECTRA 18  
1269792 Opel VECTRA 18  
1269792 Opel VECTRA 18

Comment: That's why you shoudl provide more details, **you** know what you want, we don't. You need to add some distinct processing. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use the [`INTERSECT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188055.aspx) clause to create this query.

It would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CarType1
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM CarType2
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM CarType3
```